# Assigning name to lines read from a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am reading a file line by line (32 lines which are in binary) then storing in a variable named `regFile[i]`. Now I have to assign a name for each line `R0` in variable `regFile[i]= 000000001000000000000` How can I assign to each line in my `regFile[i]`?? Here is my piece of code.

```
def regread(filename):

      file = open (filename, 'r')
      regline  = file.readlines()

      reg= regline
      reg= map(lambda s: s.strip(), reg)

      for i in range(0,32):
          regFile[i] = int(reg[i])
              'R'i = regFile[i]
               print 'R' ,i
      file.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why you want to name a variable - just index into `regFile`... The following is the pythonic way of writing what you have (using `islice` to make sure at most 32 lines are read and `int(line, 2)` to convert from binary to integer)...

```
from itertools import islice

with open('somefile') as fin:
    reg_file = [int(line, 2) for line in islice(fin, 32)]

print reg_file[0], reg_file[31]
```

As @mgilson points out - if you really wanted you could put them in a `dict`:

```
reg_file = {'R{}'.format(idx):int(line, 2) for idx, line in enumerate(islice(fin, 32))}
```

Comment: I want to save as R0= 1st line, R1 = 2nd line , R2= 2nd line.. because I have to use in some assembly instrucions such as : ADD R3,R2,R1. Hence I can call my regread function which can give me these values.

Comment: @user2319906 -- then put them in a dictionary:  `{'R'+str(i):x for i,x in enumerate(reg_file)}`

Comment: from itertools import islice

with open('reg.txt') as fin:
    reg_file = [line.strip() for line in islice(fin, 32)]
    while i <= len(0,32):
      dic={'R'+str(i):x for i,x in enumerate(reg_file)} 
      print "dic['R']:", dic['R']                                                                                                                                I am getting error: invalid synatx error at for

Comment: remember : Here I have to read from a file and store in a variable or in a file with R0 = 010101010000000 R1= 1111111111111111111111, R2=0000000001111111111110.